# Populating linestring column based on other table values (OSM nodes/ways)

Tags: postgresql, polygon, linestring, spatial-query

I'm trying to populate a linestring column using points from another table.
After reading a lot in this site and many experiments I'm still stuck.

This is the table which I want to fill the road column:

```
TABLE planet_osm_ways
(
    way_id bigint NOT NULL,
    road geometry(LineString,3857),
    CONSTRAINT planet_osm_ways_pkey PRIMARY KEY (way_id)
)
```

and this is the table I want to get the points from:

```
TABLE planet_osm_nodes_ways
(
    node_id bigint NOT NULL,
    way_id bigint NOT NULL,
    node_number integer,
    lat double precision,
    lon double precision
)
```

What should happen is that all points with a certain way id should create a linestring in the `planet_osm_ways` table.

I come up with this query:

```sql
WITH line_table AS ( SELECT way_id , ST_SetSRID ( st_makeline ( st_makepoint( lat, lon ) ), 3857 )
AS builtedline FROM planet_osm_nodes_ways
GROUP BY way_id , node_number ORDER BY node_number )
UPDATE planet_osm_ways SET road = builtedline
FROM line_table WHERE line_table.way_id = planet_osm_ways.way_id;
```

But what this query does is to populate each way row with a linestring made by just one point. How can I make a query that gets all points for each way?

Comment: Don't group by `node_number`

Comment: thanks @ThingumaBob! it works now. i have a question, removing the group by node_number forced me to remove the order by node_number as well ( because i was getting an sql error) do you know how if there is a workaround to keep the order by node_number? i tried something like ORDER BY min(node_numer) but it didn't seems to order the right way the node.

Comment: The proper way is to put the `ORDER BY` into the function itself: `ST_MakeLine` is an aggregate/window function!

Comment: i managed to try it and worked, thanks a lot for your help @ThingumaBob!